# Conditionals not working on bash cgi

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, cgi, lighttpd

I have a working basic cgi bash script using lighttpd. This is working:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e 'Content-type: text/html\n'
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<title>test</title>'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'
echo "Hello World"
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
```

The problem is if I try to add some kind of conditional... it doesn't work. If you change only the hello world line for this:

```
if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "it worked"
else
    echo "anything else"
fi
```

It shows nothing. I tried to put them all in one line:

```
if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then echo "it worked"; else echo "anything else"; fi
```

Same result. It shows nothing.

I have a "trick" which works but is not an option to me... long to explain. It's using something like this:

```
[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && echo "it worked"
```

Any idea about what can be happening? If anybody needs more data, or lighttpd.conf or whatever just tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Does `/bin/[` exist?

Comment: yes, and it has a lot of commands inside... ls, cat, grep, if, etc...

Comment: No, does the actual command `/bin/[` exist (which should be irrelevant; most shells have `[` as a builtin).

Comment: Something else is going on; the conditional you show is fine.

Comment: Have you run it at the commandline outside the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omfg... I have the solution... I feel like a n00b. A friend of mine solved it.

As simple as change the line feeds of the end of lines from CRLF to LF on the file... This kind of s**t is what happens using Windoze... don't blame me too much and sorry for this post :( anyway I'm not going to delete it, maybe could be useful to someone.